# how could I change memory layout of multi dimensional arrays with c++

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, memory

Suppose I have a 3d array `A` with shape (H, W, C), and the memory storing them is continous, from `*p` to `*(p + H*W*C)`. I would like to change the layout of the memory storing this array to (C, H, W), which means that the original `A[h][w][c]` can be accessed with `B[c][h][w]`.

One stupid method is like this:

```
char* B = new char[H*W*C];
for (int h{0}; h < H; ++h) {
    for (int w{0}; w < W; ++w) {
        for (int c{0}; c < C; ++c) {
            int idx_old = h * H * C + w * C + c;
            int idx_new = c * H * W + h * W + w;
            B[idx_new] = A[idx_old];
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any c++ built-in function to do this ? Or what is the fastest method to do this with c++ please ?

Comment: Modern compilers are pretty good at optimizations, have you benchmarked (an optimized build) to check that it isn't "good enough™"? Is it a top-three bottleneck in your program?

Comment: With my limited knowledege, this looks fine. Node that you could also use the new dimensions `(C,H,W)` order to go through the array. I do not know if this can make any real difference. But this way the writing would be to linear memory, instead of the reading.